# Remove ad banner completely when button click

Tags: android, textview, admob, banner

I placed an ad banner on my app and want to remove it and the text completely when the user taps the text. The following code works however when i close and restart the app, the banner and text reappears again. 
Should i set the visibility to gone? if i do that wouldn't it mean that the ad banner still exist but cannot be seen (does that violate the AdMob TnC ?).Thanks

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AdView Adview;
TextView textView6;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    Adview=findViewById(R.id.adView);
    textView6=findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()/*.addTestDevice("")*/.build();
    Adview.loadAd(adRequest);

}
public void onClickValuation(View view) {
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,ValuationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void onClickItem(View view) {
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,ItemActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void onClickAds(View view){
    ViewGroup parent1 = (ViewGroup) Adview.getParent();
    ViewGroup parent2 = (ViewGroup) textView6.getParent();
    parent1.removeView(Adview);
    parent2.removeView(textView6);
    parent1.invalidate();
    parent2.invalidate();
}
}
```

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.42"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickAds"
    android:text="Don't like seeing ads? Tap Here!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Write persistence logic ( Database / file / shared preferences ) and check if user clicked previously and then only load ad. For Data and file storage refer this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Sample Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView6=findViewById(R.id.textView6);

    if(!IsUserRegistered()){
    MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    Adview=findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()/*.addTestDevice("")*/.build();
    Adview.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}

public void onClickAds(View view){
    ViewGroup parent1 = (ViewGroup) Adview.getParent();
    ViewGroup parent2 = (ViewGroup) textView6.getParent();
    parent1.removeView(Adview);
    //Ad is removed now update UserRegistered
    UpdateUserRegistered(true);
    parent2.removeView(textView6);
    parent1.invalidate();
    parent2.invalidate();
}   

private boolean IsUserRegistered(){
//User Data Persistance to check if value is set and return that value
//https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage
    return false;

}

private void UpdateUserRegistered(Boolean bUserRegister)
{
//User Data Persistance to update user send value
    //https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

}
```